# Create list of controls

Tags: vb.net

I seem to not getting it, I'm trying to create some kind of list in Visual Basic where each item isn't just a string but a bundle of labels, a button and maybe a picture.
I've already written some programs in VB but I just don't get how I'm supposed to start this, sorry, maybe I'm just missing out some elements or something like that.
Anyone got an idea?

Comment: Something like  Dim controlList As New List(Of TextBox)
        controlList.Add(txtSearch)  where txtSearch is a TextBox.  You can also create textboxes on the fly and add them to your list.

Comment: @Brian Hibbert also works with textbox + button per item? o:

Comment: One of each per item?  You might need to create a class (say MyControls) that contains a textbox and a button, save pointers to the 2 controls in instances of the class and make the list of MyControls

Comment: A `List` (and most of remaining .NET collections) admits any `type`; as far as all the controls inherit from the `Control` class, the most logical approach seems to rely on this class. That is: `Dim list As List(Of Control) = new List(Of Control)`. There you can store any control (e.g., labels, buttons, etc.). Alternatively you might rely on a different approach (as what Brian is suggesting above). You have many options and this question is too abstract to be on-topic here.

Comment: @Brian Hibbert that sounds exactly like what I need, however, looks like I'm just not experienced enough with VB to understand what I have to do sorry, so could you describe it a little more detailed or at least give me some links?

Comment: I'll post more details as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is highly simplified, and for illustration only.

I've created a class that is nothing more than 2 properties to hold pointers to a related set of 1 button and 1 textbox.

```
Public Class MyControls
    Property theTextBox As TextBox
    Property theButton As Button
End Class
```

Then in my code that needs to store the controls together in a list:

```
    Dim controlList As New List(Of MyControls)
    Dim item1 As New MyControls
    item1.theButton = New Button
    item1.theTextBox = New TextBox
    controlList.Add(item1)
```

After than you can get access to the controls by selecting the items from the list and using the dot operator.

```
   controlList.Item(0).theTextBox.Text = "New text"
```

---

Adding these to a ListView depends on how you want them displayed.  The hard part is deciding there to put them... This example just adds the textbox and displays the button below it.

```
controlList.Item(0).theButton.Text = "press me"
ListView1.Controls.Add(controlList.Item(0).theTextBox)
controlList.Item(0).theButton.Top = controlList.Item(0).theTextBox.Height
ListView1.Controls.Add(controlList.Item(0).theButton)
```

Comment: Thank you, I finally understand this now, thx for your patience. How would you display this in a listview? Or is there a proper way to display this?

Comment: I edited the answer to make it clearer... see above.